# Getting error in new Ember-cli project

Tags: ember-cli

I tried to create a test project with Ember-cli to try out things in isolatoin, but was running into this error were the server wouldn't start.

```
$ mkdir ember-cli/
$ cd ember-cli/
$ ember init
$ ember server
version: 0.1.2
You have to be inside an ember-cli project in order to use the serve command.
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot name the directory "ember-cli" or "test". The directory is used as the project name and these are reserved words.